# PHP- Trying to convert Mysqli to PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to convert the Mysqli code to use PDO

Mysqli code looks like the following (which works great)

```
$rs = "SELECT * FROM team";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$rs);           
$data = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$responses = array();
    if($data != 0) {
        while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
        echo "<tr><td>".$results['code'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$results['username'] ."</td>";                   
        }
```

---

My PDO code I tried

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from  team");
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
 $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

How should I write a while loop here

on w3schools website, the information given to retrieve the records using PDO is as below, which did not say what is V and doesn't say how do I retrieve the fields `code` and `username` from the table.

```
  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any PDO code for the loop yet?

Comment: use for loop, and count the size of $result to run the loop accordingly or foreach whatever required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a horrifically awful way to select data from a database. It's far more complex than is necessary. I suppose it *might* be useful in a certain context, but not here.

The simple way is with [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). This works in much the same way as `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. (You don't strictly speaking need to check the row count, though you might have other code if there are no results.)

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['code'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['username'] ."</td>";                   
}
```

My preferred way, however, is with `PDOStatement::bindColumn`, which gets rid of arrays and uses nice plain variables instead:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stmt->bindColumn('code', $code);
$stmt->bindColumn('username', $username);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr><td>$code</td>";
    echo "<td>$username</td>";                   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's PDO, so [everything is MUCH simpler](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach):

```
foreach ($con->query("SELECT * FROM team") as $results) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$results['code'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$results['username'] ."</td>";                   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from  team");
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['code'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['username'] ."</td>"; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rs = "SELECT * FROM team";
$stmt = $pdo->query($rs );
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row ['code'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row ['username'] ."</td></tr>";  
}
```

or

```
$stmt = $pdo->query($rs );
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row ['code'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row ['username'] ."</td></tr>"; 
}
```

or

```
$data = $pdo->query($rs )->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row ['code'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row ['username'] ."</td></tr>"; 
}
```